# Getting Permanent API key for Riot

Tags: python, riot-games-api

I am currently using Riot API to run my program on python to access League of Legends player status. However, every time I run my code, I have to refresh my Riot API key, which will become inconvenient to the users. Is there any ways to get a permanent Riot API key or refresh it automatically?

Answer (score 1):

You can submit an application for a permanent API key
https://developer.riotgames.com/app-type